# Why has '-' been chosen as the backup file suffix for certain Unix system files?

Tags: backup, filenames, history, etc

Example: `/etc/group-`, `/etc/passwd-`

Is there any motivation behind choice of the `-` sign (e.g. easier to recognize, process, etc.)?

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think that convention is widespread at all. This may be quite idiosyncratic to `/etc/passwd` and friends. Similar conventions that *are* widespread are `filename~` (for backups, convention from `emacs`) and `filename--` (something intentionally disabled by the sysadmin).

Comment: Some unix systems have the old passwd backupped as opasswd

Comment: @wurtel. *Backup* is a noun (as is *setup* and *login*). In each case, the verb form is two words, a prepositional verb: hence *back up*, or, in the past tense, *backed up*. You may find your English flows more smoothly if you follow these guidelines, and you will not have to create monstrosities such as *\*backupped*.

Comment: @Celada my `filename--` is a newer backup of `filename`, because `filename-` is already taken by an older backup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using prefixes or suffixes is common, because it's easily filtered.

It's usually `~` for backup. Most text editors use this, and it is possible to explicitly tell `ls` to not list them by default. This is similar to using a period at the beginning to make the file somewhat hidden (this is also respected by `ls` and by shell globbing). Other examples are `#filename#` used by emacs for storing *unsaved* modifications of a file (so that you can recover if you didn't save something). This one is usually meant as *temporary* file (not exactly backup) and is usually shown by file listing tools.

The usage of `-` in the case of user account management files is somewhat unconventional (I don't recall any other occurences of this suffix). It may be from the prehistoric versions of unix (someone should comment if they know). However there is a subtle difference here. The `~` mostly means that a user modified a file and a backup was stored by the text editor. The `-` suffix is used by the automatic tools for user management. It's not there so much to reverse syntax errors or file corruptions, but to revert a correct (but unwanted) change. It's not uncommon to have both files present if you happened to edit the files by hand at some point. For instance, I sometimes have 3 extra files:

```
passwd, passwd~, passwd-, passwd.pacnew
```

the last one is a custom suffix used by `pacman` to store a file to be carefully merged into the existing file by hand.